# Android / google ANR crash without a specific cause

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

I have the following crash report from android:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
> (ActivityThread.java:2822)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
> (ActivityThread.java:2897)   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11
> (Unknown Source)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
> (ActivityThread.java:1598)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
> (Handler.java:105)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:251)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6572)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
> com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (Zygote.java:240)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

There is no specific class/file/line in my project highlighted, and there is no 'caused by' line which one would normally expect when debugging android.

Googling any individual line only seems to take me to SO questions about null pointer exceptions which this is not (and anyway I already know how to debug those, so please refrain for berating me as to debugging null pointers).

What I really need some advice on is where to start debugging/recreating a crash with this very limited trace.

Interestingly (maybe) it's only being reported on android 8.0 > but on a wide array of devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANR is short for Application Not Responding. The Android developer site has an article on debugging these [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr). The key thing to understand is that it means your app is doing something that takes a long time on the UI thread. Common cuplrits are:

- using the network
- using the disk
- some intense computation
- accessing a database

You know this is happening in `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity`.

Luckily Android is open source, so if you Google "android source performLaunchActivity" you find [the source code as the top result](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2904).

You can see this is the code that starts up your app. So something in your app start-up is running very slowly. There are lots of things you can do to investigate this:

- look for code in your app startup that accesses disk or network or database and move it to a background thread
- run your app in [strict mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode) which  will warn you of bad behaviours
- and there are a lot more tips in the article linked above.

Answer (score 0):

ANR, *Application Not Responding*, occurs when your App is doing too much of work on the main thread, generally due to disk or network I/O.

Try to check that. I think you can you [`StrictMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to debug it